# How to turn on react service worker when compatible?

Tags: reactjs

I've been using React JS service workers and it helps the users to load content faster. But I also received complaints from users who have older phones (Android 7.0, Android 5.0, etc.) that they see a blank / stale page when visiting. I realized the compatibility of service workers might not have been as good as I imagined. It doesn't seem possible to add custom compatibility check before turning on service worker.

Is there a way to check the support for service workers in the browser before registering the service worker?

Comment: Lemme know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally check the service worker support in the browser and register the service worker accordingly:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  serviceWorker.register();
}
```

To make things bullet proof, you can even check for the `ServiceWorker` object to be present.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && !!ServiceWorker) {
  serviceWorker.register();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, additional question would be what does `serviceWorker.unregister()` do? Do I need to add an `else` statement to unregister serviceWorker? My assumption is that the serviceWorker here is a react feature and it is not the equivalent of `navigator.serviceWorker`.

Comment: @AeroWang You can either register or unregister service workers, and both need the API to be active.

Comment: I see. So the better practice would be not register when not compatible (instead of unregistering), I assume.

Comment: So since `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator` is already in serviceWorker.js, it shouldn't matter if I register, but it appears that once I do my app would break, why?

Comment: @AeroWang That's weird. It should not happen. Give me some time, I am going to try this thing out in my VM. I'll get back to you soon.